# Segfault when allocating memory to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcat, strstr

I want to concatenate using `strcat` each new tag stored in a struct with char member in a the char `tags_cell_concat`. I get a segfault

**First attempt**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFDATE 50
#define BIGBUFFLEN 1024

typedef struct 
{
  char date[BUFDATE];
  char tags[BUFDATE];
  char task[BUFDATE];
  char next_step[BUFDATE];
} Record;

int main()
{
  Record *records = (Record *) malloc(2*sizeof(Record));
  // all tags: "Hello world I am a string slice function"
  strcpy(records[0].tags, "Hello world");
  strcpy(records[1].tags, "string slice");
  strcpy(records[2].tags, "function");

  char tags_cell_concat[BIGBUFFLEN] = {0};
  char *chunk;
  char *pointer;

  for (size_t i=0; i<3; i++){
    strcat(tags_cell_concat, " ");
    pointer = records[i].date;
    while ((chunk = strsep(&pointer, " ")) !=NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n", chunk);
    }
    if (strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) != NULL)
    {
      strcat(tags_cell_concat, chunk);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get a Segmentation fault at runtime

**EDIT 1**

After the comments and answer below, there is indeed a first problem with the code above (which I did not change) in that there was not enough space allocated for `records`. I changed the code to allocate enough memory but the problem persists. The seg fault problem goes away if the line 36-39 are commented out which indicates to me that the problem might lie with something with the use of the `strcat()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFDATE 50
#define BIGBUFFLEN 1024

typedef struct 
{
  char tags[BUFDATE];
} Record;

int main()
{
  size_t size = 6;
  Record *records = (Record *) malloc(size*sizeof(Record));
  strcpy(records[0].tags, "tag1 tag2");
  strcpy(records[1].tags, "tag3");
  strcpy(records[2].tags, "tag4 tag2");
  strcpy(records[3].tags, "tag1 tag5");
  strcpy(records[4].tags, "tag6 tag3");
  strcpy(records[5].tags, "tag7 tag2");
  strcpy(records[6].tags, "tag8 tag5");

  char tags_cell_concat[BIGBUFFLEN] = {0};
  char *chunk;
  char *pointer;

  for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++){
    strcat(tags_cell_concat, " ");
    pointer = records[i].tags;
    while ((chunk = strsep(&pointer, " ")) !=NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n", chunk);
    }
    if (strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) != NULL) // line to comment out and get no seg fault
    { // line to comment out and get no seg fault
      strcat(tags_cell_concat, chunk); // line to comment out and get no seg fault
    } // line to comment out and get no seg fault
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output now:

```
tag1
tag2
make: *** [runc] Segmentation fault: 11
```

**Edit 2**

I again changed the code in that I removed one Record in record so that it corresponds to allocated memory. Additionnaly I check whether `chunk` is not `NULL` in the if statement (with `(chunk !=NULL)` is it correct?). But the problem still persists. Here is the last version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFDATE 50
#define BIGBUFFLEN 1024

typedef struct 
{
  char tags[BUFDATE];
} Record;

int main()
{
  size_t size = 6;
  Record *records = (Record *) malloc(size*sizeof(Record));
  strcpy(records[0].tags, "tag1 tag2");
  strcpy(records[1].tags, "tag3");
  strcpy(records[2].tags, "tag4 tag2");
  strcpy(records[3].tags, "tag1 tag5");
  strcpy(records[4].tags, "tag6 tag3");
  strcpy(records[5].tags, "tag7 tag2");

  char tags_cell_concat[BIGBUFFLEN] = {0};
  char *chunk;
  char *pointer;

  for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++){
    strcat(tags_cell_concat, " ");
    pointer = records[i].tags;
    while ((chunk = strsep(&pointer, " ")) !=NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n", chunk);
    }
    if ((strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) != NULL) && (chunk !=NULL)) // line to comment out and get no seg fault
    { // line to comment out and get no seg fault
      strcat(tags_cell_concat, chunk); // line to comment out and get no seg faultgg
    } // line to comment out and get no seg fault
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Final edit**

Here is finally what worked for me (which is not the topic of the answer I originally posted and therefore does not constitue a valid answer). The bug was due to the condition `if (strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) != NULL)` which was changed into `if (strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) == NULL)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFDATE 50
#define BIGBUFFLEN 1024

typedef struct 
{
  char tags[BUFDATE];
} Record;

int main()
{
  size_t size = 6;
  Record *records = (Record *) malloc(size*sizeof(Record));
  strcpy(records[0].tags, "tag1 tag2");
  strcpy(records[1].tags, "tag3");
  strcpy(records[2].tags, "tag4 tag2");
  strcpy(records[3].tags, "tag1 tag5");
  strcpy(records[4].tags, "tag6 tag3");
  strcpy(records[5].tags, "tag7 tag2");

  char tags_cell_concat[BIGBUFFLEN] = {0};
  char *chunk;
  char *pointer;

  for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++){
    pointer = records[i].tags;
    while ((chunk = strsep(&pointer, " ")) !=NULL)
    {
      if (strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) == NULL)
      { 
        strcat(tags_cell_concat, chunk);
        strcat(tags_cell_concat, " ");
      } 
    }
  }
  printf("tags_cell_concat:%s:\n", tags_cell_concat);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Review the `2` in `Record *records = (Record *) malloc(2*sizeof(Record));` and `strcpy(records[2].tags, "function");`.

Comment: Is `records[i].date` initialized at all?

Comment: you are right I didn't allocated enough memory. I changed the code accordingly but the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocated memory only to an array of two elements of the type `Record`.

```
  Record *records = (Record *) malloc(2*sizeof(Record));
```

So tрe valid range of indices for accessing elements of the array is `[0, 1]`.

However you are using the invalid index `2` to access an element of the array

```
  // all tags: "Hello world I am a string slice function"
  strcpy(records[0].tags, "Hello world");
  strcpy(records[1].tags, "string slice");
  strcpy(records[2].tags, "function");
```

that results in undefined behavior.

And the condition in this for loop

```
 for (size_t i=0; i<3; i++){
```

is also invalid.

One of reasons of the errors is that you are using magic numbers like `2` and `3`. Instead use named constants.

Also not all data members of elements of the array were initialized. So these statements

```
pointer = records[i].date;
while ((chunk = strsep(&pointer, " ")) !=NULL)
{
  printf("%s\n", chunk);
}
if (strstr(tags_cell_concat, chunk) != NULL)
{
  strcat(tags_cell_concat, chunk);
}
```

also invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Many thanks @VladfromMoscow. Indeed you are right, the allocation was wrong. I fixed the code and posted the edited version down in the question. There is still a `seg fault` problem which  (I think) has something to do with `strcat()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer once again @VladfromMoscow. I found the bug: it was due to a bad if statement. I posted the code that worked for me at the end fo the question. As the bug did not have anything to do with how the original question was formulated and that you corretcly solved the original question I accepted your answer. many thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t size = 6;
  Record *records = (Record *) malloc(size*sizeof(Record));
  strcpy(records[0].tags, "tag1 tag2");
  strcpy(records[1].tags, "tag3");
  strcpy(records[2].tags, "tag4 tag2");
  strcpy(records[3].tags, "tag1 tag5");
  strcpy(records[4].tags, "tag6 tag3");
  strcpy(records[5].tags, "tag7 tag2");
  strcpy(records[6].tags, "tag8 tag5");
```

You only allocated memory for 6 elements, so the valid range of indices are `0-5`, not `0-6`.

Comment: thank you for your very helpful comments @Haris. I tried to change the code according to your comments but the problem persists. Do you have any other advice?